# Visual Studio 2005 Pre-link Event: Any way to get linker input file names?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, build-process

I've made a tool that operates directly on `.obj` files before they are linked. I can specify my tool on the pre-link event command line and manually specify each `.obj` file, but is there any macro or technique that I can use that will automatically include all `.obj` files from a particular project? There are other `.obj` files in the same directory from other projects in my solution that I don't want to include, so I can't do a `*.obj`.

The tool itself is part of the same solution. It is compiled first and then some of the other projects use this tool before they are linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I have come up with is to use a unique intermediate directory for each project. Then I can use the following pre-link event command line:

```
cd $(IntDir) && for %%f in (*.obj) do $(OutDir)\myTool.exe -flags %%f
```

When `$(OutDir)` is common among all projects in the solution, and the dependency order enforces that `myTool.exe` is compiled first, then the above works.